# Prolog: Can't see the file

Tags: prolog

I am learning how to program in prolog. I'm currently learning I/O and encountered the following problem.

I want to read the file `dane.txt` using this program:

```
czytajPlik :-
    open('dane.txt',read,X),
    current_input(CI),
    set_input(X),
    kodOdczytujacy,
    close(X),
    set_input(CI).

kodOdczytujacy :- read(Term), obsluz(Term).

obsluz(end_of_file):-!.
obsluz(Term) :-
         write(Term),nl,kodOdczytujacy.
```

However when in Prolog, when I try to use `czytajPlik.`, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: open/3: source_sink `'dane.txt'' does not exist (No such file or directory)
```

The file exists and has the proper name.

Comment: You should give the absolute path of 'dane.txt'.

Comment: Do you run the program with as active directory, the directory that contains `dane.txt`?

Answer (score 1):

The error means that the Prolog interpreter (I'm guessing SWIPl) cannot open the file, because it cannot find the file.

The interpreter looks in the directory it was started in, by default. You should either qualify the file with the path, or cd into the correct directory.

So let's say that you've started Prolog from a directory `~/prologstuff` while the file is in `~/misc`.

```
czytajPlik :-
    cd('../misc'),
    open('dane.txt',read,X),
    ...
```

or

```
czytajPlik :-
    open('../misc/dane.txt',read,X),
    ...
```

should solve your problem.